# how to generate a random 4 digit alphanumeric number in javascript that corresponds to a passed 8 digit number in a function

Tags: javascript, random, hash, digits, alphanumeric

For example if I pass any 8 digit number say 97895614 then it should return some 4 digit number (it can be alphanumeric) in a way that it corresponds only to that passed 8 digit number.

I made a function that takes any 8 digit number as an argument

Comment: How should the four digit number "correspond"? What function did you make, what went wrong with it? Where did it fail? And, also, this sounds like you're looking for some form of a hashing function; use one that already exists and has been both tested and verified. It's interesting to learn how to write one, but it's unlikely to be as secure - if it's secure at all - as one made by people that have researched the problem for years.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "corresponds only to". There are 100000000 possible 8-digit decimal numbers, but only 14776336 possible 4-character strings consisting of digits, uppercase- and lowercase-letters. So you can create a hash function that maps 8-digit numbers to 4-digit alphanumeric strings, but the mapping isn't reversible, most 4-digit strings will correspond to multiple 8-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.fromCharCode method for the string prototype :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode.

But since you use 2 digits per 'char' you will be limited in the output characters to the first 100 UTF-16 characters.

i.e :

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(189, 43, 190, 61));
// Expected output: "½+¾="
```

If you need to output a specific set of characters you'll have to add a calculation on top of your input digits, to only include this set.